# Spring mvc and iterating through a list as a form backing object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
<form:form id="myFRM" action="${myURL}" method="POST" modelAttribute="myPOJO">
<c:set var="i" scope="page" value="0"/>
<c:forEach items="${myPOJO.myLIST}" var="myItem">
  <tr class="ui-state-default" >
  <td><form:checkbox path="myLIST[${i}].aBool" value="true"/></td>
 </tr>
 <c:set var="i" value="${i + 1}" scope="page"/>
</c:forEach>
```

is there a better way to do this ?

myPOJO is a class containing a list,which I have created purely for this purpose - is there a way to reference the list directly as a form backing object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `c:forEach` tag has an attribute named `varStatus`.  This assigns a name to the loop status variable.  This variable has both the index (zero based) and the count (one based) of the current iteration.

Try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${myPOJO.myLIST}" var="myItem" varStatus="loopStatus">
```

and this:

```
<form:checkbox path="myLIST[${loopStatus.index}].aBool"/>
```

and you will not need the extra `i` variable.

Also, I suspect that you dont need the `value="true"` part for a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating the expression ${myPojo.fooBool}, which returns the String "false".

In practice what you are writing is:

`<form:checkbox path="false" value="true"/>`

So Spring is looking for a property named "false" in your bean (instead of looking for "fooBool").

Try writing:

`<form:checkbox path="fooBool" value="true"/>`